# R Power vs Signal Strength code

Tags: r

I'm hoping someone with fresh eyes will be able to help me out here! I am attempting to discover the power of an experiment, so have done the following:

```
height <- seq(0, 151)
social <- rpois(length(height), 9 + 0.2 * (height))
m2 <- glm(score ~ height, family = poisson)
summary(m2)
m3 <- update(m2, ~. - height)
anova(m2, m3, test = "Chi")
test.results <- anova(m2, m3, test = "Chi")
names(test.results)
test.results$"P(>|Chi|)"
test.results$"P(>|Chi|)"[2]
get.p.value <- function(slope) {
    social <- rpois(length(height), 9 + slope * (height))
    m2 <- glm(score ~ height, family = poisson)
    m3 <- update(m2, ~. - r.hand)
    anova(m2, m3, test = "Chi")$"P(>|Chi|)"[2]
}
p.vals <- numeric(1000)
for (i in 1000) {
    p.vals[-0.5] <- get.p.value(-0.5)
}
p.vals
power.of.test <- length(p.vals[p.vals < 0.05])/length(p.vals)
power.of.test
slope.line <- seq(-0.2, -1.1, -0.1)
p.vals <- numeric(100)
power.of.test <- numeric(10)
for (j in 1:10) {
    for (i in 1:100) p.vals[i] <- get.p.value(slope.line[j])
    power.of.test[j] <- length(p.vals[p.vals < 0.05])/length(p.vals)
}
plot(slope.line, power.of.test)
```

However, this produces:

```
In rpois(length(height), 9 + slope * (height)) : NAs produced
```

I've obviously made a silly mistake somewhere and have spent all day retyping it to make sure I'm not missing a parenthesis, etc but everything seems to be in order. I have a feeling it's something to do with the 9 and slope value, which I obtained from a glm, but this could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you care to indent and comment your code?

Comment: Your poisson rate (lambda) can not be less than 0.

Comment: Sorry about not indenting. I really don't understand the poisson rate, could you explain in further? The only things I can see under 0 are the -0.5, but I've copied those directly from my notes. I'm rather hopeless at R, sorry.

Comment: `rpois` generates a random number from a Poisson distribution.  The 'rate' is the parameter that the dist'n needs (representing the average number of events occurring).  Start by reading here: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Answer (score 1):

The error you pointed out is found in `get.p.value(-0.5)`. Looking inside the function shows that your are giving this (`-0.5`) value to `rpois`, which cannot take negative number as argument.

I really do not know what you want to do, but you might run your code with `get.p.value(0.5)` instead.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: right after `for (j in 1:10) {` put in `browser()` 
... then before submitting the code at the command line type: `options(warn=2)`

So when you get an error or a warning (which I what I think that message is), you can inspect any of the variables to get their current values. The default value for warn is 1 and you should set it back when done.

(I suspect, along with you ,that you will find that 9-(-some_slope)*some_height gives a negative value for the rpois call. (The expected value to rpois *does* need to be positive, right?)

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

In the `glm` function you have "score" but that is not defined.  Do you mean "social"?
In the `for` loop you have `for(i in 1000)`, I think you mean `for(i in 1:1000)`. Also

```
 p.vals[-0.5] <- get.p.value(-0.5)
```

doesn't iterate over `i` and `p.vals[]` indicates indexing...which doesn't make sense when you're talking about the -.5th element of `p.vals`.

Finally the line

```
test.results$"P(>|Chi|)"[2]
```

gives me a result of 3.16 * 10^-107, which is real real close to 0.  This makes sense to me, because I think you code is asking "if I remove all information from the model, what is the value of having any information?"

I could be off base here... but hopefully this helps you!

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it to work, but my slope vs power graph is so weird.